# How to update multiple object children fields using the ES6 spread?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

We have the options for `react-graph-vis` in state:

```js
{
    options: {
        physics: {
            enabled: false
            ...
        }
    }
    nodes: {
        font: “12px sans-serif #888f99”
        ...
    }
}
```

We want to update `options.physics.enabled` and `options.nodes.font` with props from the parent component without removing or editing any other default options in state:

```js
<Graph
    graph={this.state.graph}
    options={{
        ...this.state.options,
        physics: { enabled: {this.props.isPhysicsOn}},
        nodes: {nodes: {font: this.props.isNodeLabelShowing ? ‘12px sans-serif #888f99’ : ‘12px sans-serif transparent’},
    }}
    events={this.events}
/>
```

Am I holding it wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first spread is great, you just need to spread for the children objects too.

```
<Graph
  graph={this.state.graph}
  options={{
    ...this.state.options,
    physics: {
      ...this.state.options.physics,
      enabled: this.props.isPhysicsOn
    },
    nodes: {
      ...this.state.options.nodes,
      font: this.props.isNodeLabelShowing ? '12px sans-serif #888f99' : '12px sans-serif transparent',
    },
  }}
  events={this.events}
/>
```

You’re correct in that you are removing all other fields in `physics` and `nodes`. Try this ^^ out.